The future of the Worldbuilding-Process and Worldbuilding-Resources tags
For the purpose of this question I am going to focus on worldbuilding-process because the issue was invoked via this question on Main, but everything I'm about to say is equally applied to worldbuilding-resources. For the purpose of this question the consequences apply, IMO, to both tags equally. If we're going to embrace one, it makes no sense to not embrace the other. So, as you read, remember that both tags' proverbial heads are on the chopping block.
There was a day when the sun rose high in the sky...
To plagiarize one of my favorite authors1: What would happen if we remove every effort to explain the act of worldbuilding from WB.SE? Answer? A mere ball of flaming gas would illuminate the world.
That's actually a fairly succinct way of explaining my complaint about WB.SE becoming Physics-lite. But I digress.  What's the point of my point?
If we are nothing more than an idea factory for other people's individual and ego-centric (used in a loving way, mind you) worlds, then we've intrinsically failed the intent and goals of Stack Exchange. If we, of all websites on Earth, are not the place for people to find answers to the question, "how do I build imaginary worlds?" then we've all stopped believing in the fundamental purpose of Stack Exchange: to help people to become better at what they do.
By the way, that plagiarism was created by someone who IMO really understood the process of worldbuilding. That jazzy quote foiled an idea within his world: the difference between a ball of flaming gas and a sun is perception and the culture and beliefs that support it. But I'm digressing again. Kinda. Don't lose track of this.
On August 31, 2015, during the fifteenth Fortnightly Challenge2 the community specifically invited questions tagged worldbuilding-process
That challenge resulted in 19 questions and 96 answers! WB.SE had been around only a year. It was still working out the details of existing. But they knew then that the site wasn't intended to be someplace where someone could simply get help building a world.
They knew it was also where someone could learn how to be a better worldbuilder.3
What do we want to become?
A lot of sunrises have occurred since those early days and not a few flaming balls of gas and it's time for us to reevaluate what we want to be when we grow up. A large number of questions over the last two years that were tagged worldbuilding-process really weren't asking for help about the process of worldbuilding — they were (as is so common today) merely asking for help building their world. Those questions properly tagged and asking to better understand the process of worldbuilding were consistently closed.
Because Stack Exchange has changed over all that time, too. And so too, have we.
Here is a sampling of related Meta questions. These are both specifically about the tags and ideologically (IMO) important to this discussion. I'm sure others apply. If you feel one not listed here should be listed, please feel free to do so.

What's up with the [worldbuilding-process] tag?
How should we treat documenting worldbuilding?
Does the Stack wish to allow questions concerning the profession of worldbuilding?
Case Study Series
Are questions about how to develop worldbuilding software on topic?
Could Neverland be built on Worldbuilding Stack Exchange today?
Should we try to create Storybuilding.SE?

What are our options?

A place that simply gives fish to people? There's a lot of fun to be had doing this! It's more about the creative and imaginative aspect of worldbuilding. These are the kind of questions newer users can participate in because they can be creative without really knowing for themselves how to build worlds. It's the difference between asking a teenager to explain how to write good poetry and reading the poetry they've written. They really can't do the first (other than to repeat what they've read in a textbook), but they can do the second! And while it's rarely great, it's often good. That's what giving people fish is really about. The handful of experts give great answers, but almost anyone can give a good answer.

Door #1 means the two tags are whether literally or not, burned. We no longer accept any such questions on this Stack and accede entirely to Stack Exchange's current set of rules which, frankly, pretty much burn both tags because there are far too many resources covering far too many topics and the effort of worldbuilding spans far too many disciplines that can be approached in far too many ways and, we must admit, there simply isn't (in many cases) one best solution.

Or a place that teaches people how to fish. This requires questions to be just as focused and answers to be just as rational... but they're not as fun. Fewer people can give good answers, much less great answers, and it's not unsurprising that the people who want to participate but find they cannot choose to down vote or vote to close. Worse, we seem to have become convinced that how-to-fish questions must only be answered with just one answer or they're not valid questions while give-a-fish questions are more than happily answered with any number of answers. But, perhaps most complex of all, they tend to violate SE's rules today as they're always a bit open-ended and the answers always a bit all-of-equal-value.

Door #2 means we intentionally create an exception for both tags and future users will point back to the answers found here to justify a suspension of the rules so that we can share our collective wisdom about the how-to and with-what aspect of building worlds. We know these are exceptions and when we find users down voting or voting to close because The Rules are being violated we politely remind them that it's a Community Policy to let questions using these two tags pass — assuming they meet the expectations of the tag wikis. (And users advocating for door #2 might want to read the tag wikis and mention whether or not they need to be improved to allow them to pass through door #2.)
Of course, a third option is to keep the status-quo and continue slogging on, but I don't think that's a very responsible course of action.
So, which is it community? What's the fate of the worldbuilding-process and worldbuilding-resources tags for the next nine years? Do we burn two of the oldest tags on the Stack or do we grant them an exception?
And remember, we're talking about BOTH worldbuilding-process AND worldbuilding-resource — because I think it's a waste of time to ask fundamentally the same question twice.
One last thing...
Before commenting or answering below, please take the time to read both tag wikis. Especially the worldbuilding-process wiki. It's probably the best defined tag on the entire Stack despite it having fallen to one of the least used (and least understood) tags.

Should the Worldbuilding-Process tag be discontinued?


1 Terry Pratchett, specifically Hogfather.
2 The Fortnightly Challenges were first contemplated on Feb 9, 2015 and survived 28 challenges until finally discontinued as a regularly organized event on Apr 12, 2016. Their purpose was certainly to generate questions on a new Stack — but as pointed out by
HDE 226868, they were also to increase the use of underused tags. That need remains and it's ironic that one of the tags focused on during those challenges, worldbuilding-process, has since become again an underused tag.
3 Curiously, if you go wandering through those early questions, you'll find a treasure trove of information about the process of worldbuilding even though nearly all never used the tag. The questions simply weren't generally about any person's specific world. IMO we're today no longer worldbuilding.se, we're storybuilding.se... we've simply not bothered to change the name. How, then, to get back to our roots explaining to people how to fish rather than giving them fish?

The only definitive thing is death. All the rest is negotiable at any time.

Pterry. There is a mastercourse in world presentation in every novel!

I think I might disagree that Door No 2 "creates an exception". Clearly, the history of the forum itself indicates that meta questions (not Meta), those of process, those of resources, those of the intellectual activity itself, those of nature, philosophy & school, are all integral to the mandate of this community. This might be less about creating an exception and more about stating anew what we're all about as a community.

@L.Dutch And here we are, negotiating.

@elemtilas That would make a good answer, but note that at the moment a disgruntled new user has voted to close the List of Worldbuilding Resources asserting it isn't a retaliation vote but simply holding the quesiton to the same standards I hold other questions. I consider the LWR to be an on-topic Finite List of Things - but I can't ignore the fact that the List can grow indefinitely. So, think through what you mean by there not needing an exception to the rules we have today, not a decade ago.

@JBH -- If this is Grey Sheep, then we must have radically different ideas on what constitutes a "new user", gruntled or otherwise! If he's "new", then I just started yesterday! I agree with you. It's reasonably finite. But more importantly, an open list is  not infinite. This list could indeed grow. But also, it might yet be pruned. And even if it grows unwieldy like some vine in the garden, it can always be broken up into smaller pieces. For example, rek pined that it needs more resources for A-H. If the single list proved too large, we could always make more focused lists!

@elemtilas Curious that I just made this statement about another user who's kicking against the proverbial pricks. Time doesn't make a person wise, but experience and a willingnes to learn. As I get older, I find that I have less patience for people who complain that they're not being treated equal when they've done so little to contribute to the whole. Thanks, as always, for your insight.

If we can't ask about how to build worlds and about resources relevant to building worlds, this isn't a site about world-building, it's just a glorified catch-all site for the leavings of other SE sites.  Sure, to use JBH's metaphor, we seem to hand out fishes a lot here, but we should never shrink from teaching querents how to fish for themselves.
Obviously, I'm all in favour of keeping these tags and everything that goes with them, and I agree that we shouldn't be closing these sorts of questions as readily as other questions get closed.  There are reasons to be closing worldbuilding process/resource questions... such as lack of clarity, but otherwise, answerers should respond with their own approach/resources, even if the sum total of answers might fail the book test, or if the question might seem to be asking more than one thing.
Perhaps we should also be editing question tags to put worldbuilding-process and worldbuilding-resources where they belong.

As much as I'd like to write an answer, Monty sums it up well: obviously, these tags are a vital part of what Worldbuilding.SE is all about.

I wholeheartedly agree with the admonition that we should be actively adding and, likely a whole lot more, removing those tags to be sure they're used properly.

@JBH Tags exist to guide users to questions.  It does behoove us to make sure that questions are appropriately tagged.

For my money the question noted is mis-tagged, it is not about what I consider worldbuilding, rather it's about presenting an already built world to an audience. That's a question of formatting and storytelling no longer about creating the world. That's my two cents on the particular case.
As to the general question I feel, and I know no-one will wholly agree with me (just as I will never wholly agree with anyone else), that the process and resource tags are vital to what we do and what we want to be about, but that they may have largely played that role out. We are in the enviable position of being able to use a finite set of tools and methodologies to produce an almost infinite variety of results. The OPs brilliant list of resources will hopefully grow over time as people create more complex and specific datatables and calculators that we find too good to ignore, without getting too unwieldy. The processes people use to execute their worldbuilding universally boil down to a matter of inspiration and scheduling; where do you look within the world you are building to inspire your next question and in what order. Some people start with a big chunk of story then build the world outward from there, some start high concept and work down into the stories, some start with the substrate, etc... but the options are finite, personal, and like I say all basically consist of "where do you start?" and "what order do you like to proceed in?".
The material we have from these tags absolutely needs to be preserved, and in fact highlighted. I'd also love to see more individual, somewhat unique, takes on the worldbuilding process. What I don't want to see is a lot of questions using these tags, particularly worldbuilding-process as a justification to reinvent the wheel again and again because when all is said and done each and every one of us has their own take, or several, on how best to approach projects.

I'm curious to know your views on this issue: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8384/40609
